# How to match a transaction of incoming tx on blockchain with the one in DB?

Tags: transactions, wallets, raw-transaction, transfer

I'm working on a TG bot used for exchange of crypto <-> fiat.

Each customer gets assigned  a single wallet, **once**, which he is to send coins to, however he wants to, priour to receiving fiat.
Namely, `telegram_user_id -> one_wallet`.  The same wallet then gets used by a user for all future transactions

A bot, on the other hands, is supposed to identify whether or not a wallet has been topped up for a certain deal or trade. Once topped up, an operator gets notified and gives fiat to a customer.

**Issue**: how to identify if a certain incoming transaction corresponds to a particular trade?

Namely:

- A customer could, theoretically, open a deal and abandon it.
- A customer could also open 5 subsequent deals, abandon first 4, and then proceed only with the latest one -- send coins to a wallet.
- A customer could open a deal, send coins, receive fiat and then open a new deal **for the same amount** right away.
- And I can't force a customer to attach a special *deal ID* to a transfer because not all the wallets, nor even blockchains, support this.
- The sum of a deal may not be used because it's not unique.

How would a bot identify which transaction on blockchain, in a wallet, belongs to which deal of a user?
And whether there's even been any transaction for the current deal at all?

---

Note that it works the way I've described - in Telegram. There're no smart contracts, nor web3 wallets on a website, and this is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> Each customer is assigned a wallets

> Issue: how to identify if a certain incoming transaction corresponds to a particular trade?

#### Suggested solution

Each trade gets assigned a wallet.

See how Coinbase is using `CREATE2` opcode: https://www.coindesk.com/markets/2019/08/14/coinbase-is-using-an-ethereum-upgrade-to-help-merchants-accept-usdc/

> “[With CREATE2] I can show you an address that doesn’t exist on the blockchain but that you can pay to.”

---

> There're no smart contracts, nor web3 wallets on a website, and this is a requirement.

At some point, somewhere, somehow, you need to create wallets for the users. You may as well create wallets for transactions.

Cost of creating a wallet = $0.

Cost of sweeping the wallet to the destination = gas fee only.

Comment: I have no idea how this is supposed to be a solution. `[With CREATE2] I can show you an address that doesn’t exist on the blockchain but that you can pay to.` --> every possible  address in Ethereum already exists on blockchain, whether it may have been explicitly generated by someone, or not

Comment: Once again: in my TG bot, each user get an address ONCE, and PRIOUR to a creating deal. Not each single time a user makes a deal, but once. A wallet then gets used by a user for all future transactions

Comment: Then my answer will be "I don't know". You may or may not ignore the suggestion of creating the address per transaction, not per user.

Comment: My comment will be "you don't know what you're talking about".

Comment: I wish I could downvote myself. Not possible though. My assumption is that your goal is to have a working product, happy customers, charge small fee here or there, make profit, be happy, accomplish self-actualisation (top of the hierarchy of needs).  One option is to stick to your requirements (my answer "I don't know") or just change the requirements slightly... **MAYBE**

Comment: No problem!! I can downvote you! Also, I have a few people - friends of mine - who I too could ask to downvote you!